# Low voltage asymmetric duty cycle oscillator

Tags: led, pwm, oscillator, low-voltage

I'm designing a low voltage (1.6 V and less) LED decoration.
The source voltage is a low power, high impedance energy harvesting source.
With the following characteristics: deliver between 0.8 and 3 V with a resistance of near 3 kohms.

For now I have designed a small oscillator with MOSFETs which runs from 0.6 V to feed a low voltage shift register.
The goal is to establish a stable oscillator, and driving circuitry before lighting up the LEDs. That's why I take care of having a control circuitry working with voltage lower that the LEDs.

Oscillator:
[image]

I have understood than by toggling the LEDs really fast, I can reduce current consumption, and have some pause between LEDs lighting up (so loading the energy stocking capacitor). And maybe work with even smaller power inputs, with the same luminous energy.

*For that I'm looking for an oscillator circuit which works with low voltages, and with an asymetric duty cycle so the capacitor as more time to charge than for lighting the LEDs.*

Any suggestions?

I have looked at astable relaxation oscillator, but no opamp reach my needs (low voltage). And I also tried to put two capacitor very different on the upper circuit without results...

Comment: You say this: `For now I have designed a small oscillator with mosfets which runs from 0.6V to feed a low voltage shift register` then you ask for an oscillator circuit. I'm confused.

Comment: It sounds like you are making life really hard. How much current can you source from your harvester? Can you step up the voltage to something more useable, perhaps via an LTC3105?

Comment: Take a look at the [LM3909](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/291791248394336/LM3909%20Datasheet%202.pdf). It's an obsolete chip, no longer manufactured (but you might still be able to buy one). But you might get some useful ideas from its schematic diagram and understanding how it works internally.

Comment: @Andyaka as stated, the oscillator designed as a symmetric duty cycle. Which doesn't meet my needs

Comment: @winny Current draw during boost startup make this unlikely, as the amount of energy to start-up the boost converter is by far superior to the one needed to light up some LEDs

Comment: It’s specifically made for energy harvesting from weak sources. How much current can yours supply?

Comment: I have worked with this, and I can tell for a fact the current draw at start up, even with the inrush limiter is to important. Moreover, the added cost, bom list and surface is too important. The current supplied, depends on the proximity with the primary source. And range from 500uA to around 5mA in the best conditions. In this case, the luminous intensity of the LED is very satisfying. And so I'm working on the lower part of the working spectrum for the second version.

Comment: I can’t see it from the limited information you have given, but you are limited to a fairly slim selection of MOSFETs available at 0.6 V, hence my suggestion to start thinking about boosting said voltage. From there, you can make a circuit do what you want with uA of current for the logic and the rest to your LEDs.

Comment: What makes you think you can design this without design specs? I created my own design specs to generate this.   https://tinyurl.com/ybvlmlrh

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/y9udd4b6

Answer (score 1):

### Design specs:

Astable Oscillator, asymmetric output < 1.5V 1Hz,  low current < 0.5 mA, high intensity Red LED.  Not using  0.6V threshold FETs that cost $6

### Solution

[Sim](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YwrCAWATNWBOAzAhYCMSwMAODDEWCeC8gUwFpdcAoAdxEaUSJAO4W7CseYPtyRFR4IeMnEEXKQCd2+BR3YB2AGzh2MfU2W8Fx3Nt2wt+wUYkm7ZnZSsxDIOe3Hui83Nl3MAMYqnI7C3GEQYNDWuPB00UgaMGiwsBIYaAhoWphk0TBB3r7mMppOUNZo1TW1dWggCZBIWRoIsC1YWhrVuE4xzGweYR5IOFIALjx2SJbFPHMQuJUaSEh9bbhgCHEIxALNObAbbbAYaVr87hAAJjQAZgCGAK4ANhPSIuXTYovSDqUvrMnEwpsZgSEFhVltFskgtGM-CJ1jsNDDIMc0NszvCcgR8DoMLcHi93kJ1GF1GMokwAEqQq6XBRRRBLSD5XTRWBMADmkKSoVURPkNL5o1W82FnKYAA92OgeKozA11vBfDoAMLMOUYMyKsikDSKnTqkAapCykBEeDwpZgHTwsimgCK2vcWIWDR2y3hnBdFpwZFwaE44LGPHGSyQAH1gdGwNGdmAY7hmrB45BcNGGLHo-hoxgmIGeBLjFLqQEs3GE0mY9EEenYdmq3ms4XixgCJ5uOdQlZdEQ8+J44mtnXIA2Mwhm7nB+3COx-PgIuY+iyNEPBzWxxnJ9EszmYxvC31OMN-MNSiA7k83hM6K8aDd2JzKnghB4rsMvIIAPbsMgmRNIgNBtZox2IcQwGOMZcn6fQYR4PQQC0Jh-1UJko1gBB+g6HBsg0CQtCsLQOiNApChfUIzzQlCUJFcosXgCi8DfVjQzowtiHlEAADFEOWMgGBAAA1X93keHkaCYIA)

Abrupt switch turn or RESET is often needed at low voltage where gain margin is low.

### Simulation results

f= 1.05 Hz @ 1.3V  PASS
duty cycle= 30%    PASS
Power Input= < 100 uW peak, 55 uW average  PASS

Optical LEDs don't work well at a lower voltage
Current limiting is required for LED if supply goes to 3V and source impedance needs clarification.

Comment: Quite convenient little simulator! Thank you very much for your time and effort.
I ruled out those types of oscillators thinking they couldn't make asymmetric outputs.
I will import your schematic in LTSpice to simulate with my models!

If you're looking at a MOSFET with a 0.6V range look the DMN231 it is around 0.2$

Once again thank for the help

Comment: Yes it works surprisingly well with experience.

Comment: With various LTSpice simulations done, the components are ordered, I will let you know of any progresses !